# .stringsdict not working in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift

having some issues using .stringsdict. Code like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>groups-selected</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@groups@</string>
        <key>groups</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d group selected</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d groups selected</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>friends-online</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@friends@</string>
        <key>friends</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d friend online</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d friends online</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>points-usage-message</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@points@</string>
        <key>points</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d point will be deducted</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d points will be deducted</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The localization works find in iOS9+ in the simulator and on the device however for iOS8 it won't work on neither and I'll just get the key name output i.e.: `points-usage-message`. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: How to you call NSLocalizedString in code, can update the question with code for that part?

Comment: @KexAri any luck? Can you check answers or add some code as Maxim Mikheev asked.

Comment: @KexAri any luck? Facing the same issue...

Answer (score 9):

Check http://maniak-dobrii.com/understanding-ios-internationalization/ , specially the part that says:

"A quick gotcha for .stringsdict: don't forget to have (at least empty) .strings file with the same name for each localization you support, otherwise .stringsdict won't be recognized and used."

In my case, I had a localised .stringsdict file and a non localized .strings file. iOS9 was able to show the correct translation, but iOS8 failed miserably

Comment: This fixed our problem with iOS 8 not picking up the .stringsdict file. The file had the incorrect format, so there was no localizable option to select for it.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it occurs to work on iOS 8.4. We're also using `.strinsgdict` format. So i added this code:

```
<key>points-usage-message</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@points@</string>
    <key>points</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>d</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>%d point will be deducted</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%d points will be deducted</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

to our file and it work properly, when i retrieved it with this code:

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"points-usage-message", nil), 42];
```

or swift:

```
let localizedFormat = NSLocalizedString("points-usage-message", comment: "")
let pointsInfo = String.localizedStringWithFormat(localizedFormat, 42)
```

Please try that code and share the results. 
Also you could additionally try to check `.strinsgdict` file target membership and localization (should be set to some country).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
<string>%#@points@</string>
<key>credits</key>
```

to

```
<string>%#@points@</string>
<key>points</key>
```

for you `points-usage-message` string.
Both `string` and `key` have to be the same.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Also to note. The .stringsdict and the .strings file have to be located at the root of the Project.
Otherwise they are not found.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar trouble on Xcode 9 and I had to delete my .stringsdict file, recreate it, drop it into the root project folder and then add it to the target.